# cryproot-unlock with dropbear: Timeout while waiting for askpass

Tags: debian, luks, debian-stretch, dropbear

I installed Debian 9 on a VPS and configured the root partition to be encrypted. However, due to the installer giving me trouble when attempting to encrypt, I had to do this manually.

To be able to unlock the root partition via SSH during boot I also installed `dropbear-initramfs`and updated the initramfs using `update-initramfs -u`.
On boot, I am now able to connect to the `dropbear`server.

After the login process, `cryptroot-unlock` (which is invoked automatically when logging in via SSH) fails with the following error message:

```
Error: Timeout reached while waiting for askpass.
```

and closes the connection.

I didn't find anything on this exact error message on the web and tried to make sure I didn't make any config mistakes, but nothing seemed to help so far.

At the moment, I am able to chroot into the system using a rescue live system; what can I do to fix this error?

Answer (score 3):

I was able to fix the problem myself, but maybe someone else runs into the same problem, so I'll post the solution here:

As it turns out, my `/etc/crypttab` had syntax errors, which led to `askpass`(amongst others) not being included in the initramfs when running `update-initramfs -u`.

For me, it was enough to add each separate logical volume into `/etc/crypttab` instead of the volume group as a whole. Here's an example:

```
#name       underlying device       passphrase  cryptsetup options
vg-root     /dev/mapper/vg-root     none        luks,retry=1
vg-swap     /dev/mapper/vg-swap     none        luks,retry=1
```

After updating your initramfs once again your system should ask for the logical volume passphrases on startup and then resume booting normally.

Answer (score 0):

Writing this here as I have found this thread while trying to solve the same issue on *Kali Linux*.

On Kali in particular there is a package installed by default which is `cryptsetup-nuke-password`. This replaces /lib/cryptsetup/askpass with a script that calls the original ‘askpass’ binary and renames askpass to /lib/cryptsetup/askpass.cryptsetup ([see here](https://www.mail-archive.com/debian-bugs-dist@lists.debian.org/msg1688262.html)), causing the same exact error when using `cryptroot-unlock`:

```
Error: Timeout reached while waiting for askpass.
```

A possible solution is to edit `/usr/share/cryptsetup/initramfs/bin/cryptroot-unlock` to point to `/lib/cryptsetup/askpass.cryptsetup` instead of `/lib/cryptsetup/askpass`:

```
ASKPASS=/lib/cryptsetup/askpass.cryptsetup
```